# Is Drupal 8 ready for big website development?

Tags: 8

I have a good experience with Drupal 7 and build many website using D7 Verison.

Now, i am in process of building a new big website with plenty of user interactions by collecting data from webforms...

And to avoid the nightmare of ugrading my website from D7 to D8 1 or 2 years later... So i decided to start my new project using the D8 version.

I was checking some of the modules required by my project and found that almost all modules do not have stable releases yet (Yellow Color)

The website will be heavily based on:

- Rules
- Group
- Webform
- Bootstrap Theme
- Quick Tabs
- Display Suite
- Footable
- Field Permissions

---

UPDATE (MORE IN DEEP EXPLANATION)

1) There is no team behind the project, only 2 person are working in this project with very limited coding capability but good knowledge about Drupal, modules and its functionality...

2) The project is personal so no one is hiring us and we hope within around 2 months we will have the first stable release of the website online.

3) The website concept is pretty simple and forward, for example:

_ Webform a user can fill it to answer some question.

_ Automatically creating of nodes upon webform submit using rules.

_ Grouping registered users on the website within Groups (Please note i am using "Group" module and not the "OG" module.

_ Sending a simple email for administrator when a user sumbit a webform.

_ Display created nodes using views.

_ No complicated requirement is needed for such project, at least for the coming 2-3 years from the website launching date.

_ Open Webform in dialog (Popup window)

_ Ajaxify all pages, nodes... (maybe not all but most of them) (I mean by ajaxify is loading content withoit refreshing the page)

WHAT DRUPAL 8 IS OFFERING OUT-OF-BOX:

_ Views.

_ Dialog (open any link with the specific class)

_ Entity reference field

_ Telephone field

_ Ajaxify (Not sure if come out-of-box)

_ Long support (maybe 6-7 years ahead)

_ Quick edit

_ Responsiveness.

_ More faster and more secure.

_ many other features...

NOTE:

_ the project is doable with Drupal 7 but i am affraid from the time and effort required to migrate from D7 to D8 especially when i will have around 100000 registered users and around 500000 nodes
(After max 1-2 years from the project launching date)

---

I will be facing plenty issues by using such modules in D8 or they are already safe to be used ?!

In other hand, is it better to stick with D7 for time being until D8 becomes more stable ?

Thank you for your help and ideas,

Comment: There are too many variables to be able to answer this properly. It depends on the project requirements, the skills of the project team, the skills of the support/maintenance team for after the project goes live, the timeline of the project build, the budget of the project build, etc. You can however, check up on the statuses of these modules and see if they are mature enough for your liking. If you are unsure you can also do some quick prototypes of the functionality you need in Drupal 8 to see if it meets your needs, then back out and go to D7 if you have to.

Comment: I have updated my question with more explanations... kindly check it back and thank you for your support

Comment: Sorry, this just isn't generally the sort of question that Q+A can help with. The nature of the question means there can't possibly be a single, objective answer, so this isn't the right place for it

Comment: I personally view Drupal as Framework first and foremost and I never use contrib modules if I don't have to(exceptions being things like pathauto, token and so on). I always write my own code. I guess I make applications more than websites. Anyway, I personally think that if you simply want to make a website by clicking on stuff in administration, go with Wordpress instead. It will save you time.

Comment: This question is framed incorrectly as there are hundreds of D8 sites out there... and cannot have a single answer put to it.

Comment: @ElieMasaad Unfortunately more information here will probably not help. It needs to be a decision made within your team by people with all the relevant information. Hopefully my answer gives some direction in terms of making that decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I think Drupal 8 is now in a pretty stable place, where I would be confident in starting a lot of projects with it, however that is based on my experience with Drupal 7 and 8 and knowing that myself or the company I work for would be doing the work. It's also possible there would be briefs where I would very heavily consider using Drupal 7 still, depending on all the relevant factors.

There are still a number of areas where contrib modules are not yet ready for all use cases (or in some areas any use cases) without the ability in your team to either fix those modules or write your own custom code. That may or may not be okay depending on your team, budget and timeline.

There are too many variables to be able to answer this properly for your specific situation.

It depends on the project requirements (with more specifics than in your question above), the skills of the project team, the skills of the support/maintenance team for after the project goes live, the timeline of the project build, the budget of the project build, etc.

To work this out though, I recommend checking up on the statuses of these modules and see if they are mature enough for your liking. This may involve checking things like:

- What versions are available?
- How many people are using the Drupal 8 versions?
- How many issues are open for D8 versions? Are they bugs or feature requests? If they're feature requests are the missing features ones you need? What kind of support requests are being created and do they make it seem like there are some issues?
- If the module is not ready enough, how active is the maintainer? When were the last commits, etc.

In some cases those things might be enough to satisfy you that you have enough knowledge to decide. In others you may still be unsure, in which case I would quickly stand up a dummy Drupal 8 site for some prototyping, install the modules you want to check and try them out. See if they are as stable as they claim to be and that you can do what you need.

Then you an decide if it's ready enough, or if it's not but you can deal with the missing parts within your team, or if you think it would be better to use Drupal 7 and upgrade to Drupal 8 in future.

Prototyping like that obviously takes some time, so you need to account for that in your project plan. It is however, generally significantly less time consuming than just going full speed ahead into development and then discovering later on that you can't do something you need to do and having to deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

From an overall perspective the answer to this too-broad question is:

Absolutely ready.

Safe to use.

Huge improvement.

I'm saying from my own experience.

Just one thing: Get used to Composer, Symfony and to Drupal's new configuration management. It's a bliss. Every single one of them. It will take time to adapt, yes, but after a while you'll work much more efficiently compared to D7. Symfony, OOP, standardized, everything has its place.

I recommend this official Composer template https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project and https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher to kick-start.

Don't stick to D7. It's still cool, but it's somehow a dead end (sorry). Plus you will have to migrate to D8 or D9 later anyways. With D8 the upgrade path to D9 probably will be seamless. No migration needed.

Move forward.

Comment: I don't think you can reliably say this for every use case. Would you bet your own money that someone else's team can build a site with requirements you don't know within their timeframe and budget? While I agree that it is very safe to use these days, for the most part, I would be wary of being so absolute. As an example, the OP specifically mentions the rules module, which is currently not complete and may not yet have the functionality they require. In that case, what if the team has no programming skills?

Comment: @rooby – What if the team has no programming skills? Well, does it make Drupal less ready? No. It makes the team less ready. But Drupal 8 is ready. Drupal 8 is enterprise level. So enterprise level.

Comment: Depends if you mean ready out of the box, or ready as long as you're willing to write some of the module code yourself. That's what I mean about needing to know more about the specific details of the project.

Comment: That's a very bold statement to say that Drupal 8 is ready for every use case, regardless of the technical expertise of your team.

Comment: They mention groups, which could mean the organic groups module, depending on the specific requirements, which is not ready in Drupal 8.

Comment: I agree that I would almost certainly start a project on Drupal 8, and it is definitely stable enough for most projects, but I think it is negligent to advise a less familiar person on what technology to use, so absolutely, without knowing the details of their project and circumstance.

Comment: @rooby – Let's not use comments for extended discussion. Please provide your own answer.

Comment: I have updated my question with more explanations... kindly check it back and thank you for your support